# Passing null argument to v8 callback

Tags: node.js, v8

I have a native addon that implements a function that accepts a callback and calls that callback with a possible error and a result.

I currently have the following code from NodeJS documentation that calls that callback directly with the result:

```
v8::Local<v8::Function> callback = v8::Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
const unsigned callback_argc = 1;
v8::Local<v8::Value> callback_arguments[callback_argc] = { physical_drives };
callback->Call(v8::Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), callback_argc, callback_arguments);
```

In certain cases I want to call the callback with a `null` first argument:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value> callback_arguments[callback_argc] = {
    v8::Null()
    physical_drives 
};
```

This fail as I cannot initialise `callback_arguments` with `v8::Null()` or `v8::Undefined()` as those functions return a `v8::Primitive` while `callback_arguments` contains `v8::Value`s.

A manual cast was not possible neither:

```
v8::Local<v8::Value>::Cast(v8::Null());
```

What's the correct way of passing a `null`/`undefined` value to the callback?

Comment: Did you try: `v8::Local<v8::Value>::New(v8::Null())`. Also I would consider using NAN (https://github.com/rvagg/nan) as it will shield you somewhat from v8 changes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`v8::Primitive` is a subclass of `v8::Value` so it is absolutely fine to upcast it. The code does not compile because you can't downcast `v8::Handle` to `v8::Local`.

Just change the type of the `callback_arguments`:

```cpp
v8::Handle<v8::Value> callback_arguments[callback_argc] = {
    v8::Null(),
    physical_drives 
};
```

This should compile just fine.